# How to install and run elasticsearch in Vagrant?

Tags: elasticsearch, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I'm trying to install and run Elasticsearch in Vagrant. The issue is that when I try to run elasticsearch I get the following error:

```
    log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/vagrant/elasticsearch-2.3.0/logs/elasticsearch.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:128)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:243)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [file].
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/vagrant/elasticsearch-2.3.0/logs/elasticsearch_deprecation.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:672)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:128)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:243)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [deprecation_log_file].
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/vagrant/elasticsearch-2.3.0/logs/elasticsearch_index_indexing_slowlog.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:672)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:128)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:243)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [index_indexing_slow_log_file].
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/vagrant/elasticsearch-2.3.0/logs/elasticsearch_index_search_slowlog.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:672)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:128)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:243)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [index_search_slow_log_file].
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.plugins' (/home/vagrant/elasticsearch-2.3.0/plugins)
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/vagrant/elasticsearch-2.3.0/plugins
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.ensureDirectoryExists(Security.java:337)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:314)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:246)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:212)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:118)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupSecurity(Bootstrap.java:196)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:167)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:270)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
```

I think the problem is that it has no write permission. When I do install elastic through provision I get the following permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root     4096 Apr  3 09:26 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root     4096 Apr  3 09:26 config
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root     4096 Apr  3 09:26 lib
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 11358 Jan 27 12:53 LICENSE.txt
drwxrwxr-x 5 vagrant vagrant  4096 Mar 29 08:04 modules
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   150 Jan 27 12:53 NOTICE.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  8700 Jan 27 12:53 README.textile
```

But when I do the same manually:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 vagrant vagrant  4096 Apr  2 18:20 bin
drwxrwxr-x 2 vagrant vagrant  4096 Apr  2 18:20 config
drwxrwxr-x 2 vagrant vagrant  4096 Apr  2 18:20 lib
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 11358 Jan 27 12:53 LICENSE.txt
drwxrwxr-x 5 vagrant vagrant  4096 Mar 29 08:04 modules
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant   150 Jan 27 12:53 NOTICE.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  8700 Jan 27 12:53 README.textile
```

My Vagrantfile is:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties -y
    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
    sudo apt-get update
    echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
    sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer -y -q
    wget https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/distribution/tar/elasticsearch/2.3.0/elasticsearch-2.3.0.tar.gz
    tar -xzf elasticsearch-*.tar.gz
    mv elasticsearch-2.3.0 elasticsearch
    rm elasticsearch-*
  SHELL
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run your provisioning from your file, it runs as root so the vagrant user will not have write access to your folder as you have seen.

The thumb of rule is

- `privileged: false` -> executed as vagrant
- `privileged: true` -> executed as root (default if privileged is omitted)

change your Vagrantfile to be

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    apt-get update
    apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties -y
    apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
    apt-get update
    echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
    apt-get install oracle-java8-installer -y -q
  SHELL

  config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, inline: <<-SHELL
    wget https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/distribution/tar/elasticsearch/2.3.0/elasticsearch-2.3.0.tar.gz
    tar -xzf elasticsearch-*.tar.gz
    mv elasticsearch-2.3.0 elasticsearch
    rm elasticsearch-*
  SHELL
end
```

In the first provisioning I removed all the sudo as its already the root user running the command.

The second provisioning block will be run by vagrant user and will install ElasticSearch in /home/vagrant from the vagrant user:

```
vagrant@precise64:~/elasticsearch/bin$ ./elasticsearch
[2016-04-03 10:55:01,423][INFO ][node                     ] [Araña] version[2.3.0], pid[6748], build[8371be8/2016-03-29T07:54:48Z]
[2016-04-03 10:55:01,424][INFO ][node                     ] [Araña] initializing ...
[2016-04-03 10:55:02,296][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Araña] modules [reindex, lang-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [], sites []
[2016-04-03 10:55:02,328][INFO ][env                      ] [Araña] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/sda1)]], net usable_space [35.1gb], net total_space [39.4gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
[2016-04-03 10:55:02,328][INFO ][env                      ] [Araña] heap size [1015.6mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-04-03 10:55:02,329][WARN ][env                      ] [Araña] max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process likely too low, consider increasing to at least [65536]
[2016-04-03 10:55:05,107][INFO ][node                     ] [Araña] initialized
[2016-04-03 10:55:05,108][INFO ][node                     ] [Araña] starting ...
[2016-04-03 10:55:05,228][INFO ][transport                ] [Araña] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2016-04-03 10:55:05,238][INFO ][discovery                ] [Araña] elasticsearch/gf23pBqpSs2wDrLswVeSyQ
[2016-04-03 10:55:08,313][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Araña] new_master {Araña}{gf23pBqpSs2wDrLswVeSyQ}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2016-04-03 10:55:08,341][INFO ][http                     ] [Araña] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2016-04-03 10:55:08,342][INFO ][node                     ] [Araña] started
[2016-04-03 10:55:08,366][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Araña] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
^C[2016-04-03 10:55:22,870][INFO ][node                     ] [Araña] stopping ...
[2016-04-03 10:55:22,884][INFO ][node                     ] [Araña] stopped
[2016-04-03 10:55:22,885][INFO ][node                     ] [Araña] closing ...
[2016-04-03 10:55:22,899][INFO ][node                     ] [Araña] closed
```

Comment: I tried as you said and changed the code like `config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: "false", inline: <<-SHELL ... SHELL` and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: where do you want elastic search to be installed and do you want vagrant to be the owner of ES ?

Comment: I want elasticsearch to be installed in `/home/vagrant/` and yes, I want vagrant to be the owner of ES. Truly speaking, I just want to write my Vagrantfile then `vagrant up` and all the stuff to be installed. Then I just `vagrant ssh` and launch elasticsearch without any troubles.

Comment: ok should just work - updating my answer, it works for me locally

Comment: i see you changed your answer a little bit. So try now `vagrant destroy` and then again `vagrant up`.  Does it work?

Answer (score -1):

From your Guest:

```
$ cd /home/vagrant/elasticsearch-2.3.0/
$ sudo chmod -R a+w logs
```

And for safety, you could also do...

```
$ sudo touch logs/elasticsearch.log logs/elasticsearch_deprecation.log logs/elasticsearch_index_indexing_slowlog.log logs/elasticsearch_index_search_slowlog.log
```

And then reboot and/or reprovision from Host

```
$ vagrant reload
```

or

```
$ vagrant reload --provision
```

or

```
$ vagrant halt && vagrant up --provision
```

With the last two commands ideally doing the same thing, although I have noticed some weirdness when running reload as opposed to halting/upping.